# Defective Black Eye Macro 64

Tags: blur, smartphone, accessories

I bought this black eye for my iPhone and the instructions are very simple: Place the lens on the camera. I did so and and I see is a blurry display through my phone. I put the sense on properly without any dust and it is entered properly. Is this a defective product or am I doing something wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's a defective *class* of products.

Comment: @xiota I’m pretty happy with the Moment brand. Only ones I’ve seen worth their cash though...

Comment: Try focusing on things **with your phone very close to them**. *Close*, as in the add on lens is almost touching them. Closer than what your phone can normally focus on. What happens then?

Comment: I've never heard of these things. Can you explain what it is _supposed_ to do?

Comment: You've put a cheap reading monocle on the eye of your phone, so it is having trouble seeing distance. I can relate.

Answer (score 9):

A diopter lens* like this is really only supposed to work at VERY close distances, which your unmodified phone or camera lens won't focus to (otherwise, there is no need to use a diopter). From the picture, it looks like you are holding the camera a two feet or more away from the subject - the phone can likely focus on that just fine without a diopter. Try using it on a subject just an inch away - that is what the specifications say, "20-26mm focus distance".

If you need magnification of a far away subject instead of close ups of something very near, you need to shop for a "telephoto", not "macro" accessory.

This accessory enables "microscope", not "telescope" behaviour.

*This would be the precise term to a photographer. "Macro lens" is ambigous, it could mean a diopter attachment for either a phone or camera, but a camera store would assume you want to buy a complete interchangeable lens for a DSLR/DSLM camera, worth hundreds of dollars, if you ask for a macro lens.